# How to create a policy in Terraform to send emails

Tags: terraform, amazon-ses

I have an SES account for sending email from Amazon AWS
I want to create a policy for it to be able to send mails
How can I do it with Terraform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "policy_§sender_ses" {
  statement {
    actions = [
      "ses:SendEmail",
      "ses:SendRawEmail"
    ]
    resources = [
      "*"
    ]
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "policy_companysender_ses" {
  name        = "policy_companysender_ses"
  path        = "/"
  description = "Policy to allow email sending for companyrama company sender"

  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.policy_companysender_ses.json
}

resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "roles_policy_companysender_ses" {
  name       = "roles_policy_companysender_ses"
  roles      = [var.role_name]
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.policy_companysender_ses.arn
}
```